# How to make sorting function for ListView in WinJS?

Tags: javascript, listview, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I have the following list:

```js
var myData = new WinJS.Binding.List([
  { title: "001", text: "one", picture: "/images/001.png" },
  { title: "009", text: "nine", picture: "/images/009.png" },
]);
```

I tried to filter my list by using this code, but failed:

```js
var filtered = myData.createFiltered(function (item) {
    return item.title == "001";
});

WinJS.Namespace.define("Sample.ListView", {
    data: filtered
});
```

How to make the "createFiltered" function work?

Comment: Can you show your ListView HTML and how you assign the data source to it?

Comment: @ Kraig Brockschmidt Sure, here it is:
`
<div id="listView"
class="win-selectionstylefilled"
data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
data-win-options="{
  itemDataSource: Sample.ListView.data.dataSource,
  itemTemplate: select('.smallListIconTextTemplate'),
  groupDataSource: Sample.ListView.data.groups.dataSource,
  groupHeaderTemplate: select('.listLayoutTopHeaderTemplate'),
  selectionMode: 'none',
  tapBehavior: 'none',
  swipeBehavior: 'none',
  layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout, groupHeaderPosition: 'top'} }">
  </div>
`
BTW, I used [this sample](http://try.buildwinjs.com/#listview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what you've showed here, the problem isn't with the filtering, which is working correctly if I remove the groupDataSource and groupHeaderTemplate from the data-win-options string of the ListView. If you use grouping, then you have to have called createGrouped on a WinJS.Binding.List and use that as the data source, otherwise it's groups.dataSource property will be null. The sample you refer to shows this, but in your case, having created only a filtered source, there is no grouping to work with and you get a crash.

That is, with the JS you show, the following HTML works fine, as I've omitted the group references:

```
    <div class="smallListIconTextTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none">
    <div class="smallListIconTextItem">
        <img src="#" class="smallListIconTextItem-Image" data-win-bind="src: picture" />
        <div class="smallListIconTextItem-Detail">
            <h4 data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h4>
            <h6 data-win-bind="textContent: text"></h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="listView" class="win-selectionstylefilled"
     data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
     data-win-options="{ itemDataSource: Sample.ListView.data.dataSource,
        itemTemplate: select('.smallListIconTextTemplate'),
        selectionMode: 'none', tapBehavior: 'none', swipeBehavior: 'none',
        layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout, groupHeaderPosition: 'top'} }">
</div>
```

Here's the example from try.buildwinjs.com that does the grouping (and assumes English sort order):

```
var grouped = myData.createGrouped(function (item) {
    return item.title.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
}, function (item) {
    return {
        title: item.title.toUpperCase().charAt(0)
    };
}, function (left, right) {
    return left.charCodeAt(0) - right.charCodeAt(0);
});

WinJS.Namespace.define("Sample.ListView", {
    data: grouped
});
```

Just to mention it, this grouping function is NOT world-ready, as it assumes a sort order based on ASCII position. A real sort function should take localized sort order into account, which is demonstrated in the Windows SDK HTML Listview Grouping and Semantic Zoom sample, specifically in [groupedData.js](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-grouping-and-6d032cc1/sourcecode?fileId=50880&pathId=1971622911). Of course, that's shows doing this in WinRT whereas the try.buildwinjs.com has to be generic. In any case, it's an important consideration for grouping and sorting that I wanted to mention in this context.